# Singularity of Burgers equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> It is well known that without viscosity the time evolution of Burgers equation results in singularity $v∝x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

I read this in a research paper. Can anyone explain what the meaning of "singularity $v∝x^{\frac{1}{3}}$" is?

Edit:
Burgers equation takes the following form:
$$v_t+vv_x=\nu v_{xx}.$$

Comment: You've neglected a huge amount of information. What research paper? Which version of Burgers equation? Is $v$ supposed to represent the solution to the equation? If so, is $v = v(x,t)$ or are there any extra parameters? And which part of the statement 'singularity $v \propto x^{1/3}$ were you confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^{1/3}$ is singular in the sense that it is not differentiable at $0$. But you have not given enough information to decide whether a solution could tend to this
at some time, or even what the word "results" means in the sentence.